# Disk-first caching strategies failing

Tags: workbox

Sorry, but I have no idea how to reproduce this. I am merely trying to understand what's happening at this point.

I'm working on a PWA that has several routing strategies defined. Over the past day, the service worker got into a bad state.... as near as I can tell without being updated.

The exhibited behavior was the sw hanging while trying to fulfill requests. With trial and error I was able to trace it down to my fallback route - removing this route (or bypassing sw entirely) fixed the problem.

Furthermore, it was only an issue when this route attempted to fetch from disk first - specifying networkfirst or networkonly resolved the issue.

I attempted to clear the cache as well as specifying a new cache suffix. None of these resolved the issue. New service workers happily installed and served up the same blank page.

In the end, a browser restart seems to have resolved the issue. I can't reasonably expect end-users to restart their browsers because they get a blank page. I'd really like to understand what has happened so I can prevent it in the future.

Possibly related, I am in the process of building out a new web platform and it is fairly likely that workbox got a 40x or 50x somewhere along the way. I am only 'intentionally' caching respnses of 0 and 200 on the problem route.

This is the route

```
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp(/^(?!.+\/weather?|.+__utm.gif?)/),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'resources',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 250,
        maxAgeSeconds: 86400 * 30       // 30 days
      }),
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        statuses: [0, 200]
      })
    ]
  })
);
```

However, I stripped it down to this, without effect:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp(/^(?!.+\/weather?|.+__utm.gif?)/),
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'resources',
  })
);
```

As I said this is the fallback route. Everything really critical is being handled by preCaching... however this fallback is still causing the entire page to hang.

Along the way, I updated to workbox 3.3.1, but it seems the bug was embedded in my browser by that point.

Browser info : 67.0.3396.62 (Developer Build) built on Debian buster/sid, running on Debian buster/sid (64-bit)